# EKEventEditViewController EKAlarm alert titles corrupted

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar

I'm facing an issue with `EKEventEditViewController`.
When the user adds a calendar event using `EKEventEditViewController` and wants to set an a reminder, the text of alert time intervals isn't what I expect.

For example "1 hour before" text, appears like "interval_miniutes_long before"

On the previous IOS and IOS 14 simulator, it works fine. Is it an IOS bug?

Comment: I don't see any complaints about this on iOS14, from your example looks like more a localisation problem.

Comment: I cleaned localization files and this bug persists, also with simulators the same behavior 
IOS 13 in below no issue and works fine